# CoffeeScript syntax highlighting in Chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome, coffeescript, syntax-highlighting, google-chrome-devtools

I have enabled source maps and workspaces in Chrome Canary to be able to edit *.coffee files directly in the browser. Yet the default editor in Chrome does not have syntax highlighting for CoffeeScript files, at least I could not find it. Is there a way or extension to enable that?

Answer (score 4):

This was recently implemented in https://codereview.chromium.org/18341003/

Comment: sweet, do you know when it'll be live in canary?